# after turning on switch button its impossible to turn it off

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

how can this switch button be turned off? Here is the code:

```
<Switch
         onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({falseSwitchIsOn: true})}
        onTintColor='#42dff4'
         value={this.state.falseSwitchIsOn} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it like this

```
<Switch
         onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({falseSwitchIsOn: value})}
        onTintColor='#42dff4'
         value={this.state.falseSwitchIsOn} />
```

Comment: When I added 2nd switch they both are turning on together how can they be separated?

Answer (score 0):

you should did

```
<Switch
  onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({falseSwitchIsOn: !this.state.falseSwitchIsOn })}
  onTintColor='#42dff4'
  value={this.state.falseSwitchIsOn} /> 

 <Switch
  onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({falseSwitchTwoIsOn: !this.state.falseSwitchTwoIsOn })}
  onTintColor='#42dff4'
  value={this.state.falseSwitchTwoIsOn} />
```

Comment: When I added 2nd switch they both are turning on together how can they be separated?

Comment: I updated the answer you should use another state object like this.state.falseSwitchTwoIsOn etc